# Automate the option setting for an itemize inside an environment

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, itemize, options

I was asking myself if there is a way to automate the option setting inside one of a document's environment? For instance, I have an `itemize` block inside a `tcolorbox` environment, inside it I set my `label` to `\textcolor{myColor}{$\bullet$}` while they are simply black outside this block. Is it possible to automate this setting?

My example here use a `itemize` inside a `tcolorbox` but I wanted to know if it's possible to automate option when working in a given document environment in general.

I'm working with the `pdfLaTex` compiler and here is my minimal code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.68, 0.05, 0.0}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exmp}[3][]{
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{myColor},
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt,
    fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
    coltitle={black},
    label=#2,
    title= {\textcolor{myColor}{Example~\thetcbcounter:} #3\\},
    attach title to upper,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    frame hidden,
    colback=white!80!gray, 
    #1
}

\begin{document}
A simple itemize outside my environment:
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}

\begin{exmp}{ex:myEx}{My example}
A itemize that I custom in an environment: 
\begin{itemize}[label=\textcolor{myColor}{$\bullet$}] % Option I want to automate
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}
\end{exmp}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for the development on the method to follow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `\setlist` to the `code` key-value:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.68, 0.05, 0.0}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exmp}[3][]{
    breakable,
    enhanced,
    borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{myColor},
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt,
    fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
    coltitle={black},
    label=#2,
    title= {\textcolor{myColor}{Example~\thetcbcounter:} #3\\},
    attach title to upper,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    frame hidden,
    colback=white!80!gray,
    code={\setlist[itemize]{label=\textcolor{myColor}{$\bullet$}}},
    #1
}

\begin{document}
A simple itemize outside my environment:
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}

\begin{exmp}{ex:myEx}{My example}
  A itemize that I custom in an environment: 
  \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
  \end{itemize}
\end{exmp}

A simple itemize outside my environment:
\begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \item C
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```